# Disable AOP in Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have an app with `spring-jdbc` dependency (which also brings `spring-tx`). I don't use Hibernate, and I don't need any automatic transaction management. Also it's a Kotlin based app, which means that most of the classes are `final`.

Unfortunately the `spring-tx` automatically turns on the AOP, which tries to make a proxy for my beans. Which fails with `Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class ... Cannot subclass final class`.

Since I don't need any of the features of automated transaction management, I want to disable AOP, proxying and tx management. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you try removing the @EnableTransactionManagement annotation if it is present in the code ? [@EnableTransactionManagement](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html) . From the documenation -  *@EnableTransactionManagement and <tx:annotation-driven/> are responsible for registering the necessary Spring components that power annotation-driven transaction management*

Comment: It doesn't present. Just having `spring-tx` in the classpath enabled it automatically (using the Spring Boot), so I'm looking how to _disable_ it if it was already enabled by a 3rd party.

Comment: I found a workaround actually, I don't like the approach by it's probably the only way I found. Going to post it as own answer, if there is no better solution.

Answer (score 2):

It was `PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration` that was trying to enable AOP disregarding that there were no need for it.

Disabled it with:

```
@SpringBootApplication(
        exclude = {
                PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration.class
        }
)
```

Most of the docs say to disable only `DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration`, `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration`, `TransactionAutoConfiguration`, etc, but apparently that's not enough.

In general, the full config could be:

```
@SpringBootApplication(
        exclude = {
                DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class,
                HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
                AopAutoConfiguration.class,
                JtaAutoConfiguration.class,
                TransactionAutoConfiguration.class,
                PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration.class
        }
)
```

It seems that it should disable all magic related to databases. Though in my case `PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration` was enough.

Comment: Did you try excuding [`TransactionAutoConfiguration`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/transaction/TransactionAutoConfiguration.html)? . Also not tagging the question with spring-boot was a bit misleading

Comment: yes, tried, it was not enough. basically adding `PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration` to that list had solved the problem.

Comment: strange though that I didn't put the spring-boot tag, I was sure I added it